Why does code runs faster in VS debug. WPF
This simple test program runs considerably faster under Visual Studio Debug than in Release.
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyDebugTest
{

    //test the performance of task switching in VS Debug
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly Stopwatch sw = new();
        private int count = 0;
        private long target = 1000;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sw.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                count++;

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5));

                Measure();
            }
        }

        private void Measure()
        {
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= target)
            {
                lblCount.Content = (int)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                target = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + 1000;
                lblFps.Content = count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


XAML:
<Window x:Class="MyDebugTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="200" Width="450">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Padding="5">GO</Button>
        <Label Name="lblCount"/>
        <Label Name="lblFps"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>


When I run it with Debug I am getting around 180fps displayed.
When I run it without (Ctrl-F5), I am seeing around 60fps.
The first text box just displays the number of seconds since starting, to check that nothing funny is happening with the Stopwatch.
The Measure() function is purely to measure the number of operations per second. No significant processing.
I have observed this behaviour before in Visual Studio. Does it have a different way of task switching not used by standalone code? Or is it running at higher priority?

note that simply hitting Ctrl-F5 isn't release build. It is the debug build but without a debugger attached. For a release build you need to change the build configuration. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2022

Configuration doesn't matter. Attaching debugger is what makes difference. Run either version from Explorer, attach debugger, fps goes from 60 to 180.

From answer in duplicate: "... it's the system wide timer resolution. Default resolution is 15.6 ms, the profiler sets the resolution to 1ms ..." - I am sure same happens with debugger attached.
